# Ionic 2 Alert issue

Tags: angular, alert, ionic2

I have a small issue with the basic alert. so here is my scenario.
-> I click the submit button on a page and if no record returned then it will give me a alert message. I click ok to dismiss that. -- Works fine.
-> I repeat the same scenario 2nd time by providing invalid input so that i don't get record back and application gives me same alert again. I click ok to dismiss the alert -- Doesn't work.
Can any on help on this??
Here is my code to fetch the records:

```
fetchGroupMembers(form) {
    //referring this to obj because scope of this is confusing in callback functions
    var obj = this;
    //creating loader
    let loading = Loading.create({
      content: "Please wait...",
    });
    //Showing loader on current screen
    obj.nav.present(loading);
    //Send message to server to fetch the group members
    obj.myGlobals.socket.emit('fetchGroupMembers', { groupCode: form.controls['groupCode'].value });
    obj.myGlobals.socket.on('groupMembers', function (result) {
      while (obj.students.pop()); //removing all elements from array of students
      //fetching each record and creating student
      result.forEach(function (record) {
        obj.students.push(new Student(record));
      });
      //on successfull fetch dismiss the loader
      loading.dismiss();
      if (obj.students.length > 0) {
        //set students to global
        obj.myGlobals.students = obj.students
        //navigating to next page with parameters
        obj.nav.push(HostPage, {
          Students: obj.students
        });
        console.log(obj.nav);
      } else {
        //creating alert  
        obj.doAlert();
      }
    });

  }
  doAlert() {
    let alert = Alert.create({
      title: 'No Student Found!!',
      subTitle: "Please check group code. can't find students!!",
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    this.nav.present(alert);
  }
}
```

If I call the doAlert() on a button click. it works like charm. I can't figure out the problem why it isn't working in my scenario.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Could you please create a demo plunker so we can see what's going on?

Comment: I don't really know how to create the plunker for distributed code(client-server and server again further connected to mLab DB).

Comment: Seems I stumbled across a similar problem: first popup works fine, second cannot be dismissed. Submitted an issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7554 Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kC2EtfmONmJ9UxPVXkJE?p=preview @BajinderBudhwar : Ionic bug report template has a handy link to an Ionic Plunker template you can use even if you don't want to submit an Ionic bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the Alert class docs the proper way is to wait for the promise returned by the Alert.dismiss() call to resolve:

```
public TEST = () => {
    let alert1 : Alert = Alert.create({
    title: 'Prompt 1',
    message: "First",
    buttons: [{
      text : 'OK',
      handler : () => {
        console.log("First OK");
        alert1.dismiss().then(() => { // wait for the previous transition to finish or the following alert will malfunction
          let alert2 : Alert = Alert.create({
            title   : 'Prompt 2',
            message : "Second",
            buttons : [{
              text    : 'OK',
              handler : () => {
                console.log("Second OK");
                alert2.dismiss(); // DISMISSING MANUALLY
              }
            }]
          });
          this.nav.present(alert2);
        });
      }
    }]
  });
  this.nav.present(alert1);
};
```

Comment: Perfect example..!! really appreciate the help.. thanks

Comment: @BajinderBudhwar I'm glad it helped. An upvote and accepting the answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: doesn't work in ionic 2.. Any idea? It gives me `Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found`

Comment: Sorry @Bla... I'm not on this project any more